# Не могу найти причину - ошибку

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    if (event.target !== $('#nav')) {
        $('#nav').removeClass('open');
        $('#navIcon').removeClass('fa-times');
        $('#navIcon').removeClass('fa-align-left');
    }else{
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Данный код должен закрывать меню если целью клика не является блок с меню.
Но если клик именно по данному блоку то функция останавливается, 
Но после того как написал его , меню вообще не открывается .

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: Не работает с `.not()`

Answer (score 0):

Это что значит?

> функция останавливается

---

```
    if (event.target !== $('#nav')) {
```

`event.target` - элемент DOM, `$('#nav')` - возвращает динамически созданный объект-оберткy jQuery. Естественно, они не могут быть равны.

```
    if (event.target.id != 'nav' && $(event.target).closest("#nav").length == 0) {
```